# Initializing variables in one/all processes in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

I am a newbie in MPI and some things about it don't seem clear to me.

Let's say that in my program I have a matrix and processes have to transform it (each process being responsible for several columns). I have to initialize this matrix, but in order to do so, I need to get it's size from the user. I want all input/output to occure in 0th process. I can't initialize a matrix inside an `if(rank==0)`, because then the matrix won't exist outside of it. However, if I initialize the matrix outside of `if`, then won't this initialization happen in every single process? Is it ok? Doesn't it create any problems? I'm talking about some code like this:

```
struct Matrix{
    vector<vector<double>> mat;
    size_t m;
    size_t n;

    Matrix(size_t a, size_t b);
    Matrix(const vector<vector<double>> &mat);
    Matrix();
};

Matrix::Matrix(size_t a, size_t b)
{
    m=a;
    n=b;
    mat=vector<vector<double>>(m,vector<double>(n));
}

Matrix::Matrix(vector<vector<double>> const &arr)
{
    m=arr.size();
    n=arr[0].size();
    mat=arr;
}

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    m=0;
    n=0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t N;
    int rank;

    if(MPI_Init(&argc, &argv)!=MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"Error 1";
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
    if(MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank)!=MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"Error 2";
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }

    if(rank==0)
    {
        cout<<"Size of the matrix: "<<endl;
        cin>>N;
    }

    if(MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)!=MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"Error 4";
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }

    Matrix A(N,N); // happens in every process
    if(MPI_Bcast(&A, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)!=MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout<<"Error 5";
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The whole MPI system seems less logical than working with `<pthread.h>` since, if I understood it correctly, now `int main()` is being shared between all the workers and I need to use `MPI_Bcast(...)` fairly often in order for the processes to see the modern look of the matrix.

Thank you.

Comment: Very important remark: 
I tried running this sample code and if I have more than 1 process, I'm getting 'std:bad_alloc'. It looks like the reason is exactly the line "Matrix A(N,N)", so something must be wrong with it.

Comment: if you can get the size from rank `0`, then you can `MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` (on all ranks) to broadcast that value.

Comment: You can simplify your code by removing all checks for the return value - unless you explicitly instruct MPI to not crash your program upon error and instead return error codes, you'll never see anything other than `MPI_SUCCESS`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet That's what I did in the program. The question was, how to create a matrix 'A', when all processes already know its size. Should I do it in every process separately like I did?

Comment: Ideally, each rank would have a subset of the matrix and initialize them independently. If this is not feasible, you would initialize the matrix on the root rank, and then scatter it so each ranks receive a subset. and if this is also not feasible, then allocate the matrix on all the ranks, initialize it on the root rank and broadcast it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gilles Gouaillardet commented on my initialization dilemma. Concerning the fact that my code didn't compile (exited with 'std:bad_alloc'), I found how to fix that.

1. `MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)` is wrong, since `N` is a `size_t` variable, not an `int`. A beautiful answer from [Sending size_t type data with MPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807833/sending-size-t-type-data-with-mpi) fixes this by writing a macro.
   Then the correct line is `MPI_Bcast(&N, 1, my_MPI_SIZE_T, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)`. Thus, 'std:bad_alloc' problem is solved.
2. `MPI_Bcast(&A, N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD` gives a segmentation fault. Perhaps, because `A` is not quite a buffer. However, `A.mat` is, so the correct line is something like this: `MPI_Bcast(&A.mat[0][0], N*N, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)`. Now everything works fine.

Comment: You need to allocate your matrix in contiguous memory so you can broadcast in one shot.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What about doing it not in one shot? Like
for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
            MPI_Bcast(&A.mat[i][0], n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
As I understand, std::vector itself is contiguous.

Comment: Sure, you can also `MPI_Send()` and `MPI_Recv()` one element at a time.